# Faces are getting thinner as i extend them.. How do i fix this?

Tags: modeling, faces

[image: Tail is getting really thin?!?]
(I'm new to blender :) It keeps getting thinner like this when I extend the faces with >E. deleting them leaves a big face-hole at the main body. don't know how to fill it up. I just want this tail to look fatter and less ''poly-ish''(?) If its easier to fix this for me you can download the .blend here https://we.tl/t-UWNdpDSHS8. I just need help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent the tail from "thinning" as you "pull it out" you can press "shift + y" to exclude the y-axis from the transformation.
If you want to fill in missing faces select all points around it and press "f".